# How to show Paging inside footer in GridView in asp.net c#

Tags: asp.net, css, gridview

I am using paging, pageindex is 10. I am using a background color **#3F3F3F** to header and paging. If the gridview does not have 10 rows the paging is not showing and the color is not displayed so my design is not nice...
Can I keep paging numbers inside footer, so that it will give background color **#3F3F3F** to my footer..

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" ID="gv_viewincident" CssClass="gridviewdesign" AutoGenerateColumns="False" GridLines="None" EmptyDataText="No Record Found"
      AllowPaging="true" PageSize="10" 
    onpageindexchanging="gv_viewincident_PageIndexChanging" >
```

Please help

Answer (score 0):

You can use PageStyle and PageTemplate to customize the pager settings. See below snippet for e.g.

```
  <asp:gridview id="CustomersGridView" 
    datasourceid="CustomersSource" 
    autogeneratecolumns="true"
    emptydatatext="No data available." 
    allowpaging="true" 
    runat="server">

    <pagersettings mode="Numeric"
      position="Bottom"           
      pagebuttoncount="10"/>

    <pagerstyle backcolor="LightBlue"
      height="30px"
      verticalalign="Bottom"
      horizontalalign="Center"/>

  </asp:gridview>
```